# Laravel 5.5 CRUD identified by user type

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, crud

I am new to laravel and following online tutorials.I have created a basic laravel 5.5 app along with auth scaffolding which is working fine. Subsequently, I have created a form  in the dashboard which users can submit after logging in the app.

I have created an admin panel which wherein requests submitted by users will be approved. But how to identify which user has submitted a particular request?
Should i include a column in the requests table "submitted_by" and in the crud controller, save the value from auth()->user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that would be the right way I usually do something like Auth::user()->create(//Here I pass request data or variables)